# Unable to get the edge access token

Tags: edgesdk

I have created a **new** mimik developer account, and I was trying get the edge access token using the command  "***mimik-edge-cli account get-edge-access-token -t <--id token-->***". But I am getting an "**Error**" as response.

I have tried with my **previous** account and in that case i am **able** to get the access token as shown below[image]. Same issue happened for raspberrypi too.

why it is not able to get the access token while using a **new account**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure to copy the ID Token from developer portal correctly, In most cases there might be a hidden character copied. Maybe just try copying the text by highlighting with mouse from first character to the last. Do NOT use the copy to clipboard button. Also please make sure that the edgeEngine on the PI is not associated already by checking with:

```
mimik-edge-cli account get-me
```

When you input command above, if you see an ID for value "accountId:" then your PI is already associated an CANNOT be associated again. You have to un-associate first and then associate with the new ID token from new account/project. You can verify that un-association is successful when above command shows empty value for "accountId:"

FOR FUTURE REFERENCE:
Please only tag questions with edgeSDK if it is related to FreeRTOS platform. For all other platforms, please use tag edgeEngine