# Error on mimik-edge-cli account get-edge-access-token step

Tags: edgeengine

Following this manual https://developer.mimik.com/development-setup/ i stuck on a step on step 4.  ➜

```
mimik mimik-edge-cli account get-edge-access-token -t eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjV2RG45aF9LSHNxTkJZNVZubUxFd0VfUVNpQTkzZEYyN1FTQUVRdVl5T2sifQ.eyJzdWIiOiIyODczMjAwNzg1Mjk4MTY1NzYwIiwiZW1haWwiOiIyODczMjAwNzg1Mjk4MTY1NzYwQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiZGRmZmY0ODgtNDI0Ny00MWVmLTg0YTktNThiZDAxMGQ0Y2Q5IiwiZXhwIjoxNjM0MzMzODQxLCJpYXQiOjE2MzE3NDE4NDEsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbWlkLm1pbWlrMzYwLmNvbSJ9.gJAZKzRgd7QxCz-ICRoQBFAiYQvtgTzLWarhnwcH53F509iUtjtvVAdZIfnrJo4b6GBVTLJDuGghwrKk-GoppuZ66T3w-oZa-EhQ1BUTZPu49jUOium1sIR7WMSmK55UWqjr0Fsr4-4OlByHSjT4XOOiB7stLpjgDi7K8BmHIZJj1nQ-_6oi9PpVdHuQs4O0VK8ASl6wdCo_ZU5zynlA2fEve7oARW1H0r866TPc7_h5zgABnFb_RpSFyS4yQDNSoHt1E1QQ-aAr821YJoFfmoVZtBWTUvFyd_bMctt9_fZYGOvkwwoUrClFht-8okXY0m4GRWzltI4wope5lO6Bpg
"Error"
```

Node versions

```
{
  npm: '6.14.15',
  ares: '1.17.2',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  cldr: '39.0',
  icu: '69.1',
  llhttp: '2.1.3',
  modules: '83',
  napi: '8',
  nghttp2: '1.42.0',
  node: '14.17.6',
  openssl: '1.1.1l',
  tz: '2021a',
  unicode: '13.0',
  uv: '1.41.0',
  v8: '8.4.371.23-node.76',
  zlib: '1.2.11'
}
```

according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67566906/unable-to-get-the-edge-access-token
i double-checked copied ID Token and it is correct.
Platforms i used Osx and ARM. edgeEdgine is installed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - i got at answer - YOUR edgeEngine needs to be running!!!
Sorry.